# Change a single item in listview

Tags: flutter

How to draw over a single item of a listview on click?

I have a list which has posts like instagram and when the user double clicks on the list item (i.e post) the heart is displayed over the item.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: The question is about flutter (dart language) not jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
GestureDetector(
  child: /*your item*/,
  onDoubleTap: () {
    setState(() {
      /*code for adding this item to list of favorites*/
    });
  },
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use setState OnTap and update variable color.